# Create android plugin involves opencv function for unity

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, unity-game-engine

I want to create an android plugin for unity. I create plugin using eclipse. I have a bridge class in eclipse android project.

**Bridge Class :**

```
public class Bridge {

//public static Mat mRgb = new Mat(new Size(10,10), CvType.CV_8UC3 );

public static int ReturnInt()
{/*
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

            double values[] = new double[3];
            values[0] = 10;
            values[1] = 10;
            values[2] = 10;
            mRgb.put(i, j, values);
        }
    }
    double[] temp = new double[3]; 
    mRgb.get(5, 5,temp);*/
    return 15;//(int)temp[0];
}
```

I copy jar file under `bin` folder in eclipse project, paste to under `Assets/Plugins/Android`. I use this jar file below way on unity :

```
public class BridgeForAndroid : MonoBehaviour {

#if UNITY_ANDROID 
//&& !UNITY_EDITOR
public static int ReturnInt () {

    AndroidJavaClass ajc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.tutorial.pluginforunity.Bridge");
    return ajc.CallStatic<int>("ReturnInt") ;
}
#endif
}
```

Another `.cs` file :

```
private GUIContent content = new GUIContent ();
void Start()
{
    content.text = "Write here";
}

public void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height/20),content);
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) { Application.Quit(); }

    #if UNITY_ANDROID 
    content.text = "Return = " + BridgeForAndroid.ReturnInt();
    #endif
}
```

When I build & run this unity application on android device, the application works fine this way. But when I use OpenCV functions on eclipse project, the application doesn't return image value. I see only `write here` on the screen.

How can I use opencv function in android plugin for unity?

**ADDITION**

Java code that includes opencv :

```
public class Bridge {

public static Mat mRgb = new Mat(new Size(10,10), CvType.CV_8UC3 );     
public static int ReturnInt()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

            double values[] = new double[3];
            values[0] = 10;
            values[1] = 10;
            values[2] = 10;
            mRgb.put(i, j, values);
        }
    }
    double[] temp = new double[3]; 
    mRgb.get(5, 5,temp);
    return (int)temp[0];
}
```

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, the code above is the code which works. Can you please post code interacting with OpenCV which doesn't work?

Comment: you are right. The code that includes opencv is in my question text. Please remove `/*, */` in `ReturnInt ` function in `Bridge class`.

Comment: You described desired behaviour as "return image value", where exactly does it happen in your commented code?

Comment: This applicaiton is an only test application.It checks how to integrate opencv+unity for android platform.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't answer my question. You have a desired behaviour that doesn't happen, but which supposed to happen somewhere in this code. You described this behaviour as "return image value". What exact part of the code you have posted is supposed to do that?

Comment: Sorry. I edit my question text, add a code that uses opencv. Is it enough?

Comment: Thanks, although you could've just said that the cryptic phrase "image value" was supposed to be what the `ReturnInt` returns. When you ask a question on stack overflow, you have three things: (1) **desired behaviour**, (2) **actual behaviour**, (3) piece of code (usually) that should produce (1) but actually produces (2). All three need to be clear. Right now I don't have a clue what "return image value" behaviour means, and what value do you get instead: your question doesn't have adequate description of (1) and (2).

Comment: What "image value" should be? And what do you actually get?

Comment: Sorry my bad english. I expect to see `Return = 10` on the screen, but I see only `write here`. When I use opencv in android project, I don't get a value from `BridgeForAndroid.ReturnInt()`.

Comment: I see. But if you comment everything out, like in the first versoin of the code, you see "Return = 15", correct? I'm asking, because right now your code includes two different things: working with OpenCV on Java level, and transferring the value from Java to C#. And only one of the parts doesn't work. So, let's figure out which one is it, and remove the other part from the question completely

Comment: Yes, If I use first version, I see `Return = 15`.

Comment: OK, so it means that the problem is not on the Unity's side. However, it's strange that you don't see anything whatsoever. Does the code run in the second case? Don't you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I run second version on real android device. So I can't see anything console.

Comment: You can. Use adb. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html